# Opening a dialog box inside adapter returning null values

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have been trying to get this to work without success for about 10 hours now, I have looked all over stack overflow. I am trying to get a simple **dialog box** to appear and handle some simple input.

It has a **TextView** as a title, **EditText** as a input field, and two button continue with the operation or cancel.

For some reason, no matter what I do, I cannot seem to be able to reference ANY view inside my shopping_dialogue xml layout. It gives me this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference

I have tried to add an **onClick** event to the button to see if that works, when I try to reference the button inside the onClick method it gives me the same error. I am using a fragment to do this.

> **shopping_dialog.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/shoppingDialogTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Edit Shopping List Name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/shoppingDialogEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="30"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
     />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shoppingDialogOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shoppingDialogCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="k"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> **shopping_list_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:id="@+id/shoppingList_card_view"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_height="200dp">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/shoppingListParent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shoppingDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

> **fragment_shopping_list.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/shoppingList_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

> **ShopingAdapter.java**

```
public class ShoppingAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingAdapter.ShoppingViewHolder> {

private List<ShoppingData> shoppingList;
private Context context;

public ShoppingAdapter(List<ShoppingData> shoppingList, Context context){
    this.shoppingList = shoppingList;
    this.context = context;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public  ShoppingViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i){
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.shopping_list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ShoppingViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ShoppingViewHolder viewHolder, int i){
    ShoppingData data = shoppingList.get(i);
    Random k = new Random();
    int color = Color.argb(255,k.nextInt(255),k.nextInt(255),k.nextInt(255));
    viewHolder.parent.setBackgroundColor(color);
    viewHolder.shoppingName.setText(data.getName());
    viewHolder.shoppingDate.setText(data.getDate());

    viewHolder.shoppingName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setView(R.layout.shopping_dialog);
            AlertDialog alert = builder1.create();

            /*
            EditText text = v.findViewById(R.id.shoppingDialogEditText);
            text.setText("Some Text");

            This causes a null object reference

             */
            alert.show();


        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){return shoppingList.size();}

public class ShoppingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView shoppingName, shoppingDate;
    private LinearLayout parent;


    public ShoppingViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingListParent);
        shoppingName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingName);
        shoppingDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingDate);

    }


}

}
```

> **ShoppingFragment.java**

```
public class ShoppingFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ShoppingAdapter shoppingAdapter;
private List<ShoppingData> shoppingList = new ArrayList<>();

@NonNull
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                         @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){

    shoppingList.add(new ShoppingData("k","12/12/12"));
    shoppingList.add(new ShoppingData("k","12/12/12"));
    shoppingList.add(new ShoppingData("k","12/12/12"));
    shoppingList.add(new ShoppingData("k","12/12/12"));
    shoppingList.add(new ShoppingData("k","12/12/12"));
    shoppingList.add(new ShoppingData("k","12/12/12"));

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_list, container, false);

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingList_recycler_view);
    shoppingAdapter = new ShoppingAdapter(shoppingList, getActivity());
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(shoppingAdapter);

    return rootView;
}


public void k(View view){ //the click listern that causes a null object reference when referencing the button
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.shoppingDialogOk);
    button.setText("k");
}



}
```

> **ShoppingData.java**

```
package com.uhcl.recipe5nd.helperClasses;

public class ShoppingData {
   private String name;
   private String date;

public ShoppingData(String name, String date){
    this.name = name;
    this.date = date;
}

public String getDate(){
    return this.date;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

}
```

Everything works fine until I try to reference anything inside **shopping_dialog.xml**.

If you look at my **shopping adapter class**, what I am trying to do is  to add an onClick listener to the "shoppigName" text view inside my onBindViewHolder method. This works, but when I try to reference the **shoppingDialogEditText**, it causes the app the crash and give me that error.

Like I mentioned I also tried adding a click event method **k** to a button inside **shopping_dialog.xml**, and implemented it inside my fragment class to see if that would work, but it still causes the same error.

Comment: Hi, the v.findViewById is where your doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
viewHolder.shoppingName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

View dailogView =  LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.shopping_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setView(dailogView);
            AlertDialog alert = builder1.create();

            EditText text = dailogView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingDialogEditText);
            text.setText("Some Text");


            alert.show();


        }
    });
```

The view your using to the find the `edittext` is not the view of that dialog box, therefore it's throwing null pointer.

Comment: Thank you bro, I have spent hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong view to find the editText. It is not the view of dialog box. It is the view of the item which is being clicked rather than dialog box.
Use this

```
viewHolder.shoppingName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    View dailogView =  
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.shopping_dialog, null);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setView(dailogView);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

        EditText text = dailogView.findViewById(R.id.shoppingDialogEditText);
        text.setText("Shopping Dialog Text");


        alert.show();


    }
});
```

}